# Problems finding WatchKit App Store Icon

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect, watchkit

I've got an iOS app with WatchKit 1.0 support. Since Xcode 9.2 I get the following warning only for the included WatchKit App:

> A 1024x1024 app store icon is required for iOS apps

But the required image is already exists and has the correct size and format (PNG):

[image]

If I upload my app to TestFlight I get a similar warning in a dialog and per mail:

> Missing App Store Icon - WatchOS Apps must include a 1024x1024px App Store Icon in PNG format. Without providing the icon in the Asset Catalog or via iTunes Connect, apps cannot be submitted for App Review or Beta App Review. Refer to https://developer.apple.com/watchos/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/home-screen-icons/ for more information.

Adding an App Store image for iOS App works fine and gives no errors. This error only occurs for the WatchKit app.

How can I solve this issue?

**EDIT:** The error seems to be in the actool (`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/actool`) which creates the .car file from the .xcassets file. When I execute it with my assets, it ignores the App Store icon (Note: The parameters except file and folder names are copied from Xcode's compile log):

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/actool \
    --output-partial-info-plist Info.plist \
    --output-format human-readable-text --notices --warnings \
    --app-icon AppIcon --target-device watch --compress-pngs \ 
    --enable-on-demand-resources NO \
    --filter-for-device-model iPhone9,3 \
    --filter-for-device-os-version 11.2 \
    --sticker-pack-identifier-prefix com.myapp.watchkitapp.sticker-pack. \
    --minimum-deployment-target 9.0 --platform iphoneos \
    --product-type com.apple.product-type.application.watchapp \
    --compile . Images.xcassets

/* com.apple.actool.document.warnings */
/Users/clemens/Desktop/bugreport/Images.xcassets:./AppIcon.appiconset: warning: A 1024x1024 app store icon is required for iOS apps
/* com.apple.actool.compilation-results */
/Users/clemens/Desktop/bugreport/AppIcon24x24@2x.png
/Users/clemens/Desktop/bugreport/AppIcon27.5x27.5@2x.png
/Users/clemens/Desktop/bugreport/AppIcon29x29@2x.png
/Users/clemens/Desktop/bugreport/AppIcon29x29@3x.png
/Users/clemens/Desktop/bugreport/AppIcon40x40@2x.png
/Users/clemens/Desktop/bugreport/AppIcon44x44@2x.png
/Users/clemens/Desktop/bugreport/AppIcon86x86@2x.png
/Users/clemens/Desktop/bugreport/AppIcon98x98@2x.png
/Users/clemens/Desktop/bugreport/Assets.car
/Users/clemens/Desktop/bugreport/Info.plist
```

Comment: I'm seeing the same error...It was all fine before Xcode 9.2.

Comment: its works for me.. add 1024x1024 icon in .jpg format

Comment: Thanks for your hint but also with a JPG I get the same error. And according to the mail the icon format should be PNG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug doesn't appear in Xcode 9.3-beta3 anymore. So it should be fixed in Xcode 9.3.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, the image needs to be 1024x1024 and with no transparency, and I'm sure you already got that sorted out. But, that's not the issue in this case.

I know this will sound weird and unrelated, but I had the absolutely same issue on one of my projects and can confirm the fix works.
You **must** upgrade to at least WatchKit 2.0.

Comment: Does this require a mandatory reimplementation of my existing WatchKit code? So I have to rewrite my extension to run on the clock?

Comment: I'm afraid it does. The extent depends on the complexity of the watch, but there are major architectural changes in how wOS2 works opposed to wOS1.

Comment: Yes, I tried the migration some months ago. Data synchronization was very unreliable and unstable compared to WatchKit 1.0.

Comment: I can't say it's unreliable or unstable. I've been using it in production for over a year (maybe two?). It's just different. Can't expect that simply moving the same piece of code around will work.

Comment: This was no general statement about WatckKit 2.0. My app is relatively simple from the data flow and the migration seemed to me to be too complicated in terms of the expected result. And the WatchKit 1.0 solution works perfectly.

Comment: But did you try saving as a PNG without transparency? You can do it with Preview app from Mac, exporting the image and unchecking the "Alpha" option...

Comment: @vini-b-rj: The PNG has no alpha channel.

Comment: Watckit 1.0 will definitely cause this issue. You will get an email and a message in Xcode after uploading the app. I tried submitting anyway and it worked just fine.

Comment: @MosheGottlieb: I've the same email and the app is loadable with Testflight, but I think it can't be submitted for reviewing.

Comment: @clemens Just submitted again. watchOS 1 app, got complaints from Xcode when uploaded and later via email. Ignored and submitted- did that for 4-5 versions so far.

Comment: @MosheGottlieb: In the meanwhile I have submitted my app, too. Unfortunately, Apple will reject WatchKit 1.0 apps in April.

Comment: @clemens Yes, they said they would stop allowing watchOS 1 soon. I guess my only option is to remove watchOS support altogether- I’m not going to rewrite it for watchOS 2 or newer.

Comment: @MosheGottlieb: That's not just my decision. In watchKit 2 it is much more complicate.